# Interacting with HTML Page - Firefox: Content Not Defined

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a script here, which is extracting the links within a web page. It is comming back with the error '`content is not defined`'.

```
// extract the links
var links = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < content.document.links.length; i++) {
    var thisLink = content.document.links[i].toString();
    //links.push(content.document.links[i].toString());
    console.log(thisLink);
}
```

In order to interact with the HTML documents within the Firefox SDK, do I need to import a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on when the self executing anonymous function is running. It is possible that it is running before window.document is defined.

In that case, try adding a listener

```
    window.addEventListener('load', yourFunction, false);
    // ..... or 
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', yourFunction, false);

yourFunction () {
  // some ocde

}
```